# Session in files

Tags: session, core-file-storage

I use magento like API. In login controller I set into session user parameter. Session are stored in files. It work well, when I login like customer or admin. But when I will loged in after admin/customer, it will be created new session file with parameters $_SESSION['admin']['user'] and $_SESSION['customer_base']['user']. I want to store every session for loged in admin/customer in separate file.

```
public function loginAction()
{
    if (!in_array($this->getRequest()->getMethod(), ['POST'])) {
        return $this->api_helper->responseError(null, 'Only POST method allowed', 405);
    }
    $requestBody = json_decode($this->getRequest()->getRawBody());
    if ($this->api_helper->checkSecurityKey($this->getRequest()->getHeader('Security-Key'))) {
        return $this->api_helper->responseError(null, 'Security Key is Invalid');
    }
    /** @var $session Mage_Admin_Model_Session */
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $user = $session->login($requestBody->username, $requestBody->password);
    if (!$user || !$user->getId()) {
        /** @var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session */
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        try {
            $session->login($requestBody->email, $requestBody->password);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->api_helper->responseError(null, $e->getMessage());
        }
        $user = $session->getCustomer();
    }
    $session->setData('user', $user->getData());
    return $this->api_helper->response(['session_id' => $session->getSessionId()]);
}
```

I check session using custome method:

```
public function checkIsLogin($sessionId)
{
   if ($this->checkSecurityKey(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getHeader('Security-Key'))) {
        $this->responseError(null, 'Security Key is Invalid');
        return false;
    }
   if ($sessionId == null) {
        $this->responseError(null, $message = 'Forbidden', 403);
        return false;
    }
    $sessionFilePath = Mage::getBaseDir('session') . DS . 'sess_' . $sessionId;
    $sessionFile = file_get_contents($sessionFilePath);
    if (!$sessionFile) {
        $this->responseError(null, $message = 'Not found sessionFile', 403);
        return false;
    }
    $currentSession = session_encode();
    session_decode($sessionFile);
    $sessionData = $_SESSION;
    session_decode($currentSession);
    if(array_key_exists('user', $sessionData['admin']) || array_key_exists('user', $sessionData['customer_base'])){
       $user = $sessionData['admin']['user'] ?? $sessionData['customer_base']['user'];
    }
    if (!isset($user)) {
        $this->responseError(null, $message = 'Not found user', 403);
        return false;
    }
    return $user;
}
```

Thanks for help!